# c - Segmentation Fault Linked List

Tags: c

I am doing a project learning about linked list in C. While my code does compile, I get a segmentation fault when attempting to run my code. I know where the segmentation fault happens, but I am trying to figure out what is wrong with it. Here is my code:

```
//
// It reads the list from the file_name indicated. If the list already has entries,
// it will clear the entries.
//
int llist_read(LinkedList * list, char * file_name) {
        //Still Need to complete this!!!
        ListNode * e;
        int val;
        FILE *f;

        e = list->head;
        while (e != NULL) {
            e->value = 0;
            e = e->next;
        }
        e = list->head;
        if (file_name == NULL) {
                return 0;
        }
        if ((f = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
                return 0;
        }
        if (fscanf(f, "%d\n", &val, val) == 0) {
                return 0;
        }
        else {
            e->value = val; //Segmentation Fault occurs here.
            e = e->next;
            e = fscanf(f, "%d", e->value);
            while (e->next = fscanf(f, "%d", e->value) != EOF) {

            }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault here:

```
e->value = val; //Segmentation Fault occurs here.
```

Any advice as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your line `if (fscanf(f, "%d\n", &val, val) == 0) {` is problematic on numerous accounts.  Granted you are reading from a file; were you reading from the keyboard, the trailing `\n` in the format is awful.  It isn't needed when reading from the file either.  You're also passing one too many arguments to `fscanf()`.  And your test should be for `!= 1` (where the 1 is the number of values you expect to read); it can return EOF or 0 on failure, and 1 on success when you request a single conversion.  The line `e = fscanf(f, "%d", e->value);` is also badly flawed, assigning an integer to a pointer.

Comment: Your loop `while (e->next = fscanf(f, "%d", e->value) != EOF) {` is also badly skewiff.  You're assigning an integer (0, -1, or 1 — probably) to a pointer?  You've completely messed up your linked list.  You also have a problem with 'what happens if there are fewer entries in the file than in the list?' (not too serious a problem), and 'what happens if there are more entries in the file than in the list?' (a serious problem if you fix the code to traverse the list).  It also isn't clear to me that you handle reading values into an empty list correctly.  You've got quite a lot of work to do.

Comment: I now recognize these logical faults. This is what I needed to hear. I do have quite a ways to go.

Comment: Use your debugger.  Fix your numerous bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Before you assign value to `e->value`, you should check to see if there is memory allocated to `e`.  Replace the assignment statement with:

```
if ( e )
{
    e->value = val;
    e = e->next;
    fscanf ( f, "%d", &(e->value) );
}
```

You will have to resolve the loop as well within this `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for you're response. I am finding that when I try this, I can't seem to ever actually enter this loop. Any idea on how to make sure there is memory allocated to e so that I can successfully enter the if statement?

Comment: Seems like you should have allocated memory before you enter this function.  If you are not doing that, you can allocate memory inside this function when you realize that there is no memory allocated.  You can ensure this by: `if ( e == NULL ) e = malloc ( sizeof ( ListNode ) );`

Comment: While this does help me enter the if statement, I am now no longer pointing to the linked list. While I don't understand how per say, the linked list appears to be NULL. I want to manipulate this linked list more, but it has become null? Any thoughts on how to fix this?